# ManyToManyField using a select widget

Tags: django, django-forms, manytomanyfield

I have a model that has a ManyToMany field. It came from a legal database with schema predefined. When I create a model form for that model it uses a Multi select field to render the ManyToMany field. The ones that created the db want a select field instead(not multi).

```
# models.py

class MyModel(models.Model):
    mtmfield = models.ManyToManyField(MyModel2)

# forms.py

class MyModelForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        widgets = Select() #this is what I want.
```

Using select won't let me save the model using `form.save()` because it's expecting a list of values. Would It work if I "bypassed" this by overriding the save function of my model form capture the MyModel2 selected in the Selected and save it manually?

Comment: I think a `form.MultipleChoiceField` will work just as fine. It expects one or more values. You'll be able to use `form.save()`. But did you try?

Comment: Yes I did. I know it works. But I want it to look like a Select field. As a presentation.

Comment: If you want to to make it look like a Select field, do this - `forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.Select)`. This will give you a Select field but you won't be able to choose multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into using [Select2](https://select2.github.io/). It can be presented as a single select style element, but allow multiple values to be selected.

Answer (score -1):

Just add this function to your form :

```
def clean_mtmfield(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['mtmfield']
    return [data]
```